# Shell Script Error - Unable to feed output from one variable to another variable

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am getting the below error while executing a shell script: (Bash)

```
An error occurred (InvalidID) when calling the CreateTags operation: The ID ‘{‘ is not valid”
```

so when I look in to the shell script there are two lines of the script which is causing the problem, what i find is the output of Line 1 is used as a input of Line 2 (--resource $remote_snapshot_id) in my case:

Line 1:

```
remote_snapshot_id=$(aws ec2 copy-snapshot --region us-east-1 --source-region $region --source-snapshot-id $snapshot_id --description $snapshot_id)
```

Line 2:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --region us-east-1 --resource $remote_snapshot_id --tags Key=CreatedBy,Value=AutomatedBackup
```

When I try to execute Line 1, as a single command in Linux Terminal:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 copy-snapshot --source-region us-west-1 --source-snapshot-id snap-00220030300040 --description "Automated_Backup_425"
```

Output:

```
{
    "SnapshotId": "snap-00880090900090"
}
```

But the Line 2 only require the value snap-00880090900090 from Line 1 Output. (as it is currently picking entire out put starting from "{ it is giving such error as it only require snap-00880090900090)

So my question is how can i grep snap-00880090900090 & store that output to feed for Line 2 (--resource $remote_snapshot_id)

can any one help to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I grep snap-00880090900090 [from `{ "SnapshotId": "snap-00880090900090" }`]?

Since the format you intend to extract from is JSON, this is best
accomplished using JSON-aware tools. I would recommend `jq` if you can
get it installed:

```
command | jq -r .SnapshotId
```

If `command` outputs the JSON snippet you mentioned, then the `jq`
command will output just `snap-00880090900090` (without quotes, or
"raw", thanks to option `-r`).

If you cannot install a proper JSON-aware tool, can live with a more
fragile solution, and know that the snaphot ID will always have the
form shown in your example ("snap-" followed by a sequence of digits),
then you can extract it like this, using GNU grep:

```
command | grep -o 'snap-[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: Thanks @dhag **jq** did the trick for me, also out of curiosity i am asking as i see GNU grep is also useful but in my case the "snap-" is not followed only by digit it will be alpha numeric (ex: it will be like "snap-091u9a956mdd426h4") so the GNU grep syntax will be _command | grep -o 'snap-[0-9][a-z]\+_ ? is that correct. Thanks once again for the jq command

Comment: Close; you would have to specify digits and letters in the same range, e.g. `snap-[0-9a-z]\+`.